# Tacfire net protocol

Tags: networking

Now I'm  working in a system that has two machines communicate with each others  using a protocol called tacfire net protocol,  I have no information  about how this protocol  works or its message  format  I do did a lot of searches  about this protocol  but I couldn't  find  anything
So anyone could help 
And if it's  not the appropriate  place to ask please gently  tell me the right place.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4, and questions that are  trivial/irrelevant to modern networking are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I am certainly no expert here but my searching found ...

There is a U.S. military protocol called TACFIRE protocol, which appears to be a fixed format textual representation of battlefield events.  It appears to be named after the TACFIRE military computer ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_data_computer#Systems)) Could that be what you're looking for?

A report on converting this to/from other formats is available from the George W. Jr, 1995, "Automated Translation of Bit-Oriented Messages (BOMs) into Data Kernel Representations (DKRs)", U.S. Army Research Laboratory, 1995.  Available online at http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a293147.pdf

There is also good description of it (including some transport level description) here Jacques,R G, 1984, "Real-Time Message Process Simulation Capability.", http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA149017

The U.S. Defense Technical Information Center has many documents about it, and the documents show fascinating early uses and motivation behind TCP/IP.
Search here http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/

Quick reading of those documents show they call "TACFIRE protocol" pretty much anything from L1 to L7 which is used on the TACIFRE computer.

Any use?

Comment: thanks a lot but 
could you please upload this file again dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA149017 corrupted format after downloading

Comment: Downloads fine, but try http://www.dtic.mil/docs/citations/ADA149017